# EF & Summary auto generation

Tags: .net, entity-framework, summary

I have some problems with auto generation EF Model from DB. Created entities doesnt contains summary (descriptions) that I added on DB schema. Please Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean descriptions of columns or tables in the database those information are not imported by built in EF tools in Visual Studio. You will have to check if there is any other third party tool supporting this and you will also need updated code generator (T4) which will be able to pass this information to generated classes.